# How to stop subprocess.Popen('python path/file.py') from changing the working directory of the file?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have python files in different folders and I am executing all of them with a loop using subprocess.Popen('python path/file.py'), though an external python file.
My issue is: the working directories of ALL these files is changing to the working directory of the (runner) external file. I want to keep the old working directory for each executed file, is there any easy method to do it?
**Notice** this is my subprocess code for the external file:
**subprocess.Popen('python path/file.py',creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)**

Comment: What do you mean? Is the file moved or is the working directory of a **process** (which?) changed or something else?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the working directory of ALL these files is changing"? Files and executables do not have working directories – *running* programs do, and they inherit it from their parent.

Comment: Yes this is right, there is a difference between the directory of a running program and the location of an executed file. What I wanted is keeping the location of each executed file/script as a directory for the child running program, which is different from the parent's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working directory isn't *changing*, it's staying the same. Your parent process has a working directory (which may or may not be the same as the directory the script is located in), and the child processes inherit it by default. That's how working directories work (they have nothing to do with where the script is located).

If you want the working directory to match the path to the script you're launching, pass that path as the `cwd` argument to `Popen`, e.g.:

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'path/file.py'], cwd=os.path.abspath('path'), creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

`os.path.abspath` may not be necessary (I haven't bothered to check if `subprocess` accepts relative directories for the working directory), but it's not a terrible idea to do it.